# Javascript validate X number of fields in an HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form, that has about 10 text entries (user, address, email etc;)
and about 50+ entries that are quantity entries (users select 2x of this item, 5x of this item).

Now I inherited this form from someone else (now its my duty to keep it up to date, when the customer requests it).

I don't want to re-write it all, but I would like to add validation for the quantity fields.

Now the quantity fields are all named different things (b1,c55,d,12)

Basically I would like to write a script (but don't know how to search for this, or accomplish this) JS side, that would ignore the tags I know (user, address, email etc;) but check if the others are numbers (either empty - not selected, or 1-99)

Comment: Can you add script references to any of the JavaScript libraries out there? Eg jQuery?

Comment: What would be the point of referencing a js lib? I don't use one for this form.  But if someone wants to use one in their suggestion, I would welcome it.  However I don't see how it will clarify my question.

Comment: @Jakub: I wasn't asking for you to clarify anything, just asking for those who may have a solution using a particular library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a `class` to the elements (my code uses a class `check`) like so:

`<input type="text" name="b1" class="check" />`

and the following jQuery code, which will only check those elements with the `check` class.

```
$('#myformid').submit(function(){
    $(':input.check').each(function(){
        field = $(this);
        valInt = parseInt(field.val()); // value as an integer

        if (isNaN(valInt) || (valInt < 1 || valInt > 99)) // displays an error if the val is < 1 or > 99
             alert('Error in the field ' + field.attr('name') + ': must be number from 1-99'); // change this to whatever you want the form to do if there's an error
    });
});
```

Basically what this does is the following: when the form is submitted, it goes through every field you'd like it to (denoted `:input.class` to catch each field with the correct class) and checks if it's (a) a number, and (b) less than 1 or greater than 99. If it's a number and is outside the range, it alerts the user of an error. You can change the `alert()` notification to whatever error management you'd like your form to have.

Comment: @Josh Leitzel: However, if I don't want to define each name?  I have 50+ entries, and I don't care for their name, I just want to make sure that they are 1-99, or empty.  As these values change on a weekly basis, I don't want to keep updating this script.  So I would need jQuery to go through all the form elements? How would I accomplish that? What I picture is loop through like an array, and ignore the 'known' (email, first, last, etc).  Appologies if I wasn't too clear.

Comment: Sorry about that. You can use a CSS class to easily accomplish what you'd like to do. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: ahh, smart. I didn't even think to group by class.  Thank you very much!