# Javascript UK Sort code validation with three input field

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I have one payment page where I have three field called sort code each field can have 2 two digit I want to write java script code to validate this field and as user type 2 digit in first field its should jump to next field. how to validate static sort code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript validate X number of fields in an HTML form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626785/javascript-validate-x-number-of-fields-in-an-html-form)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if ($(this).length == 2) {
        $('.next-input').focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a collection of your inputs, and proceed to the next item in the collection after the second letter is typed.

```js
var $inputs = $('.input-class');


$inputs.on('keyup', function() {
  if ($(this).val().length == 2) {
    $inputs.eq($inputs.index(this) + 1).focus();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-class input-1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-class input-2">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-class input-3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-class input-4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-class input-5">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

If you'd like a more fine tuned solution, you can add as a `data-attribute` the selector of the next input

```js
var $inputs = $('.input-class');


$inputs.on('keyup', function() {
  if ($(this).val().length == 2) {
    $($(this).data('next')).focus();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-class input-1" data-next=".input-3">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-class input-2" data-next=".input-4">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-class input-3" data-next=".input-5">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-class input-4" data-next=".input-1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input-class input-5" data-next=".input-2">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

This is just the "go to next" code, no validation is performed.